# Keycloak: getting back from user profile page

Tags: jboss, keycloak, keycloak-services

In my application I have a link that redirects to the user's account page on the Keycloak server.
In this page the user can update his personal information.

The problem is that after entering his account page the user has no way to get back to the application.

There's a way to let the user get back without editing the page theme?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found the answer by looking at the freemaker template.

In my case I had to:

1. Set the application URL in the **Base URL** option in the Keycloak client settings.
2. Append the parameter `?referrer=<Client ID>` on the URL that links to the user profile page.

   ie `http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/<realm>/account?referrer=<Client ID>`

With these two settings the link to go back to the application will be visible.

Comment: Hi. I am working with KeyCloak 20.0.1 and I cant set a "Base URL" in the Client Settings. I can set a "Home URL" but even in the case I set something there, I do not see a Button if I add a param referrer={client-id} to the account url.
Also setting a referrer_uri does not work. (https://technology.first8.nl/add-manage-account-link-keycloak-redhat-sso/)

Is there a significant change in the new quarkus based KeyCloak versions?

Comment: I set the home URL and the root URL. Both are not working for me. Did you figure out how to solve this?